# Awning materials for deck under dirty trees

Tags: deck, outdoor

Our second-story deck is underneath some weeping Cherry trees and Birch trees, which drop cherries, pollen, twigs and junk 3/4 of the year it seems. I want to put an awning over the deck (there is already a frame) to keep the junk off the deck and reduce cleaning. My wife thought of aluminum door/window screen, but I know that will become caked with junk and require scrubbing with a brush. I think that standard canvas will become stained with black cherry juice, which has already stained our newly repainted deck after just 1 season.

What kind of material is available in order to:

-be easy to wash debris off with a hose

-not become stained from cherries

-allow some ambient light (ie white?)

Is there some kind of tyvek-like awning material available?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find that the best material to use is Translucent Corrugated Fiberglass Panels. These are available at building supply and some big-box stores, along with accessories and fittings needed to make a sloping roof.

[image: corrugated roofing panels]

According to product reviews: stay away from PVC because it it too brittle, and avoid polycarbonate because it is too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a material that will allow "some light in" and resist the stains of cherries. I think translucent panels will stain and because they are translucent, you'll see the stains from below.

The only material that could resist staining might be metal roof panels with a baked-on coating like a fluoropolymer (PVDF) coating, like Kynar Roof Coating...but the sound could drive you nuts in a hail storm or when the cherries are dropping.